# How to pass multiple args to npm start

Tags: node.js, npm

I am learning node js and have written some basic code just to start trying things.

If I want to pass any arguments to my application I use the following command:

```
PORT=300 npm start
```

and access it in the code using:

```
process.env.PORT
```

But I want to pass multiple arguments now for e.g.

```
PORT=3000 user=dev npm start
```

The start fails when I pass in multiple arguments.

Then I tried '&&' between arguments and it doesnt fail anymore but only last argument is successfully passed to the script for e.g. if I start the script with following command:

```
PORT=3000 && user=dev npm start
```

I can access the user argument by `process.env.user` but PORT is undefined

OR

if I start the app by:

```
user=dev && PORT=3000 npm start
```

I can access the PORT argument now but now the `process.env.user` is undefined.

P.S. I am running this on Windows environment.

Comment: `PORT=3000 user=dev npm start` should work on linux.

Comment: @Prakashsharma  
I tried this and when I access process.env.PORT i get '3000 user=dev' as one string

Comment: @Prakashsharma Thanks. That was actually the answer. But I was using a bad cmd alternative and that was causing the issue,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading your npm version and "PORT=3000 user=dev npm start" should work fine.

Comment: I tried this and when I access process.env.PORT i get '3000 user=dev' as one string

Comment: what is your npm version? It works fine for me on 3.10.10

Comment: When I do node -v I get this 'v9.3.0' and npm -v returns 5.5.1

Comment: Not able to reproduce even with npm version 5.6.0 :( Still works.

Comment: I am on windows. Does that matter?

Comment: I figured out the issue. This answer actually works. I was copy pasting the command and the cmd emulator I was using was interpreting the commands wrong but the characters were hidden so never even realized that.

Answer (score 1):

In my codebase of api, I have used the following command,

```
PORT=5555 pm2 start app.js --name API --env production -f
```

But, it was difficult every time to remember the long parameters list. I'll suggest using single pm2 configuration file rather than manually running each application. It can seperate the dev, staging and production environment using the `env` parameter. Here is the proper guide, http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/ The json format I have used and been using this for long and now very easy to handle my applications running on pm2.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You can pass these values as command line argument and you can access these in sequences in you script/code.
Like -

```
npm start 3000 dev
```

And you can access them by -

```
process.argv[i]
```

So at i=2, you will get 3000 and at i=3, you will get dev in string form.

Comment: This is not how to use environment variables.

Comment: I was telling a way to pass multiple arguments and accessing them. Nevermind, you can use this as an optional approach

Comment: I know that, but it was not what the question seeks to do. Therefore, this answer isn't really suited.

Comment: @RahulYadav I tried this but as NikxDa mentioned, I dont want to pass in arguments like this :( But thanks for the effort.

Comment: So don't use it.